# Ubuntu can't start. Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Deamon

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Yesterday I tried to install Tensorflow-gpu. I followed the instructions on Tensorflow GPU supports. 
But then today my laptop can't start Ubuntu. It keep showing the black screen.
I tried so many ways but not working.
The same message is "Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Deamon.
Please tell me how to solve it, thanks in advance.